# Have some publications on solar radiation pressure force applied Lambert's Cosine Law incorrectly?

Tags: forces, thermal-radiation, radiation-pressure

I'm trying to calculate the solar radiation pressure force on a near-earth satellite. Several authoritative sources (books, journal papers) give the force on a partly specular, partly diffusive elemental area dA as:

$$dF = \frac{I}{c}\Big[-\left[\left(1+C_{rs}\right)\cos\left(\theta\right)+\mathbf{\frac{2}{3}}C_{rd}\right]\mathbf{\hat{n}}+\left(1-C_{rs}\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)\:\mathbf{\hat{s}}\Big]\cos\left(\theta\right)\:dA$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the surface normal ($\mathbf{\hat{n}}$) and the incident radiation, and $C_{rs}$ and $C_{rd}$ are the specular and diffusive coefficients respectively.

I have no problem with almost all of this equation except for the origin of 2/3.

The diffusive component is loosely stated as being Lambertian, therefore we would multiply the magnitude of a diffusively reflected ray, $\cos\left(\theta\right)$, by a further $\cos\left(\theta\right)$ to resolve it into the surface normal direction, giving $\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)$, followed by integration across a hemisphere, supposedly giving $\frac{2}{3}$.

But $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\ne\frac{2}{3}$

$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\cos^{3}\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta=\frac{4}{3}$ which may be related, but I can't justify multiplying by an extra $\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(\theta\right)$ before integrating in order to achieve $\frac{2}{3}$.

Grateful your thoughts as to whether $\frac{2}{3}$ is valid or I have missed something.

Comment: This reference shows how to derive the $2/3$: https://books.google.com/books?id=cycsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=specular+diffusive+force&source=bl&ots=9sQ4kaUTf-&sig=ACfU3U1IIHM9vbTOJCMig-xgKn0tJWU38g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz4_i0jOjiAhWDu54KHfUBB9o4ChDoATAJegQIChAB#v=onepage&q=specular%20diffusive%20force&f=false If all the references you’ve seen agree on the formula, why would you doubt it? Your own integrations don’t make sense to me because you talk about integrating over a hemisphere but you don’t use $dA=\sin{\theta}\,d\theta\,d\phi$.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. The reason I doubted it was that I couldn't reproduce it and therefore could not apply it to extended scenarios such as earth/satellite albedo. From the top of page 149, it appears that the 2/3 results from $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\cos\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(2\theta\right)\:d\theta$ so I just need to better understand where that arises from.

Comment: Yes. I didn’t dig into where the $\sin{2\theta}$ came from.

Comment: Which books & journal papers? Pages?

Comment: Not sure why this is important to the substance of the question, but if you must know, many ranging from "Spacecraft Radiation Torques, NASA SP-8027, 1969, Page 14" through to "Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications, Vallado, 4th Edition, 2013, Page 582".